# Can you target/ modify existing classes with SCSS Modules?

Tags: sass, css-selectors, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm converting existing SCSS to SCSS Modules in a React app, and I'm having issues targeting classes specified by an external library (react-datepicker in this case).

Using modules changes the classname to something like `._DateField-module__react-datepicker__fWQOd`, but is there any way of targeting the DatePicker styles or is this not possible using modules?

**Previous Code**

DateField.tsx is just a wrapper for DatePicker:

```
<div className='date-field'>
  <DatePicker/>
</div>
```

DateField.scss successfully overrides existing styles inside the DatePicker component:

```
.date-field {
...
...
  & .react-datepicker {
    background-color: $dark-grey;
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :global to switch to global scope for the respective selector.

```
.date-field {
...
...
  :global .react-datepicker {
    background-color: $dark-grey;
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

[You don't need the & there.](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss/blob/master/src/rules/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector/README.md)

[Here's a working CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-babbage-0zkv2?file=/src/App.tsx)